# ffmpeg - overlaying images sent through a pipe onto a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay piped images onto a video and forward it as a stream.

I've tried something like below but obviously it didn't work.

```
phantomjs frames.js | ~/ffmpeg-3.2.2-64bit-static/ffmpeg -i ~/Videos/test.mp4 -filter_complex 'overlay' -y -c:v png -f image2pipe -r 1 -t 30  -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/myapp/mystream
```

Since I'm new to ffmpeg and don't quite get the syntax yet I'm pretty sure that there lies the problem so I won't be pasting the console output yet.

Notes:
phantomjs continuously produces png images;
Server is nginx with rtmp module;
I can use any recommended test video/format just to get it working;

Any help will be much appreciated.

LA

Comment: Apart from the placement of the filter_complex option, which technically should be fine, rest looks ok. Do show the console output.

Comment: @Mulvya It was it! Wrong placement of the filter_complex. Thank you!

Comment: @Mulvya ...or it wasn't. Out of curiosity I revert it to the previous syntax and it also worked. It is just working today. The setup is exactly the same regarding the server and phantom. Maybe it is not deterministic - somethimes I'm getting picture with sound but instead of original picture it is black and with something like sound histogram getting drawn.